# Mysql Table too big for only a few rows

Tags: mysql

I have a 13 rows Mysql Table that is 128Mb big (a similar table with 50k rows is only 50Mb), and I am not able to understand the reason for it.
Here the table details:

[image: user table details]

To check table size I am using the following statement:

```
SELECT table_schema "db_name", ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"  FROM information_schema.tables  GROUP BY table_schema;
```

I would avoid truncating or rebuilding the table from scratch if possible.

How can I investigate the issue?

Comment: please add sample data and table definition as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up separate tables and databases, which consist of multiple tables.

Try the following query to see how large single tables are:

```
SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, ".", TABLE_NAME) `table`,
ROUND((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "Table Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.tables
```

If a single table still occupies unexpectedly much storage, try the following query, which will free unused space in the clustered index (at least for InnoDB tables).

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE <tablename>
```

Comment: Values have changed with this statement but shows 115MB which is definitely too much for 13 rows...

Comment: @Jack Try [`OPTIMIZE TABLE <the tablename>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html)

Comment: @Jack "For InnoDB tables, […] **free unused space in the clustered index**."